# Performance enhancement for NOT IN Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I have the following Insert in an MS SQL Stored Procedure:

```
insert into Status_Table(Field1, Field2, Field3, Status_ID, Status_ID2)
select a.Field1 , a.Field2 , a.Field3 , a.Status_ID , a.Status_ID2 
  from ##StatusTempTable as a  
  where a.Status_ID+a.Status_ID2 not in(select Status_ID+Status_ID2 from Status_Table)
```

Before i do the Insert, i will check if there is any row exist with the same Status_ID and Status_ID2. Table Status_Table contains over 3 Mio rows, the Insert is getting very long. Are there alternatives to increase the Peroformance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN`

```
insert into Status_Table(Field1, Field2, Field3, Status_ID, Status_ID2)
select a.Field1 , a.Field2 , a.Field3 , a.Status_ID , a.Status_ID2 
  from ##StatusTempTable as a  
  where not exists(select * from Status_Table s where s.Status_ID = a.Status_ID AND s.Status_ID2 = s.Status_ID2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQLServer2008+ also you can use the [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement

```
MERGE dbo.Status_Table AS target
USING dbo.##StatusTempTable AS source
ON (target.Status_ID = source.Status_ID AND target.Status_ID2 = source.Status_ID2)
WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN INSERT(Field1, Field2, Field3, Status_ID, Status_ID2)
       VALUES(
              source.Field1,
              source.Field2,
              source.Field3,
              source.Status_ID,
              source.Status_ID2
              );
```